# GITHUB ACTION ISSUES

Tags: github-actions

I have being trying to work on scheduling auto-training of my model at specific time using GitHub Actions but after writing out the YAML file this is the outcome:

> The following actions uses node12 which is deprecated and will be forced to run on node16: actions/checkout@v2, actions/setup-node@v2, actions/setup-python@v2. For more info: https://github.blog/changelog/2023-06-13-github-actions-all-actions-will-run-on-node16-instead-of-node12-by-default/

```yaml
name: Update LSTM Model

on:
  schedule:
    - cron: "0 14-15 * * *"

jobs:
  update_model:
    runs-on: windows-latest

    steps:
      - name: Check Out Code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
    
      - name: Set up Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: '16'

      - name: Set up Python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v2
        with:
          python-version: '3.8'  # Specify a Python version from the available list

      - name: Install Dependencies
        run: |
          set -x
          python -m venv .venv
          . .venv/Scripts/activate
          pip install -r requirements.txt

      - name: Update Model
        run: python update_model.py

      - name: Commit and Push
        run: |
          git config user.email "user@gmail.com"
          git config user.name "user-name"
          git add .
          git commit -m "Update LSTM Model"
          git push
```

the files to be run are all available on the same GitHub repository as the workflow.

Comment: Have you considered using up-to-date versions of those actions, like it says to do in the docs linked in the message?

Comment: Oh i dont even know how to go about that. Although when i checked the actions online i discovered those actions were actually nod16 which is up to date.

Comment: Can I ask where you got the checkout@v2 (instead of v4) from? Asking because I see this used in so many places, I wonder if some documentation or tutorial with excellent SEO uses it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the action versions you are referencing in your workflow. The error is telling you exactly the problem, it just may not be obvious where/how to fix it.

Look at each dependent action:

### actions/checkout@v2

https://github.com/actions/checkout, v2 was released March 2023, which is not that old, however it is using node12. This is why you are getting the error. [source](https://github.com/actions/checkout/blob/ee0669bd1cc54295c223e0bb666b733df41de1c5/action.yml#L74-L75)

This can be resolved by using the latest version which is v4. [source](https://github.com/actions/checkout/releases)

`uses: actions/checkout@v4`

### actions/setup-node@v2

Same issue as check, v2 is from March 2023, but uses node12. [source](https://github.com/actions/setup-node/blob/7c12f8017d5436eb855f1ed4399f037a36fbd9e8/action.yml#L37-L38)
This can be resolved by using the latest version which is v4. [source](https://github.com/actions/setup-node/releases)

`uses: actions/setup-node@v4`

> Note: My guess is you probably don't even need this step, it appears your code relies on python and you inadvertently attempted to use this action to fix the node 12 error. If this is the case you can just delete this entire step.

### actions/setup-python@v2

There is a pattern here... Use v4. [source](https://github.com/actions/setup-python/releases)

`uses: actions/setup-python@v4`